# Add a new partition to Ubuntu and append it to /var/www/

Tags: server, partitioning, mount

I have installed an Ubuntu server on a VMWare workstation with a space of 20GB storage as seen below;

[image]

After the installation I've attached another 40GB worth storage to the existing Ubuntu server installation (seen below);

[image]

Now I want to add this 40GB to my `/` (root) directory or to `/var/` directory but my `df -h` result shows;

```
root@Userver:~# df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda1        18G  900M   16G   6% /
udev            990M  4.0K  990M   1% /dev
tmpfs           400M  308K  399M   1% /run
none            5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
none            999M     0  999M   0% /run/shm
none            100M     0  100M   0% /run/user
root@Userver:~#
```

What should I do now? Further, I have only ssh access to the server.

Comment: Does `lsblk` show the new disk?

Answer (score 0):

First, create a new partition on the second hard disk drive `sdb` and fomrat it, this can be done in one step:

```
# sudo mkfs.ext4 /dev/sdb -I
```

Then mount the created partition on the `/var/www/` folder

```
# sudo mount /dev/sdb1 /var/www
```

Note that the `www` folder should be empty, if not move its contents to another folder, mount the new drive and move the files back again to `www`.

To make mounting permanent so you won't need to mount the drive every time you restart the machine, add the following line to `/etc/fstab`

```
/dev/sdb1   /var/www/   ext4    defaults    1   1
```

Comment: my ubuntu server don't know the "/dev/sdb/"

Comment: i think your solution will not work , because this 
error's happened : 

root@Userver:~# mkfs.ext4 /dev/sdb -I
mkfs.ext4: option requires an argument -- 'I'
Usage: mkfs.ext4 [-c|-l filename] [-b block-size] [-C cluster-size]
.
.
.

and :


root@Userver:~# mount /dev/sdb /var/www/
mount: mount point /var/www/ does not exist



and when i restart ubuntu server there is no "/dev/sdb1" !!

root@Userver:~# ls /dev/sd*
/dev/sda  /dev/sda1  /dev/sda2  /dev/sda5  /dev/sdb